# Node Express app on Heroku Postgres H13 on database query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, http, express, heroku

I have a Node app that connects to a Postgres database on Heroku. Things work fine in my dev environment and I'm able to query with no issues.

However, when I deployed the app itself to Heroku, every time a query is triggered, I am met by a
H13 "Connection closed without response" error under both https and http connections.

I tried changing the backend so instead of performing a query, it returned hard coded values and this worked correctly so I'm thinking that the routes and stuff is fine (although the failed http request path in the Heroku logs has an extra / on the end than what is being logged when I run in dev environment, not sure if this is normal).

I am using the pg libary as follows:

```
const client = new pg.Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: true,
});

client.connect();

return client.query(query, queryParams)
    .then(res => {

        client.end();
        return res.rows;
    })
    .catch(e => {

        client.end();
        console.log(e.stack);
    });
```

Comment: By the way, here are the exact heroku logs on the error although they don't seem that useful:

assert.js:81
throw new assert.AssertionError({
^
AssertionError: false == true
at Object.exports.connect (_tls_wrap.js:1012:3)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:94:23)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:563:20)

Comment: Don't end the connection yourself. It will timeout by itself without ending it. So try removing `client.end()` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried that to no avail. Ended up getting frustrated with lack of visibility into my Heroku app that I bought an Ubuntu machine on Digital Ocean's servers and the app has been working fine ever since. Used the exact same code as above on my linux machine so I'm guessing it was some Heroku issue.